# confluentinc kafka-zookeeper docker setup not working

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am kind of stuck with setting up a working kafka-zookeeper docker setup. I am using https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper/ and https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/ My docker-compose file looks like:

```
    version: '2.1'
    services:
      web:
        network_mode: 'bridge'
        extends:
          file: web.base.yml
          service: webapp
        environment:
#This syntax of <hostname>:<port> is required by my webapp
          - kafkaHost=kafka:29092
        links:
          - kafka
      zookeeper-1:
        network_mode: 'bridge'
        extends:
          file: kafka.base.yml
          service: zookeeper
      kafka:
        network_mode: 'bridge'
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper-1
        extends:
          file: kafka.base.yml
          service: kafka
```

My base compose for kafka:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    ports:
     - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
```

Docker version:

```
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
```

Error Snapshot:

```
kafka_1         | Error while waiting for Zookeeper client to connect to the server [zookeeper:32181].
kafka_1         | java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper: Name or service not known
kafka_1         |       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
kafka_1         |       at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
kafka_1         |       at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
kafka_1         |       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
kafka_1         |       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
kafka_1         |       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
kafka_1         |       at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
kafka_1         |       at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
kafka_1         |       at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
kafka_1         |       at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isZookeeperReady(ClusterStatus.java:73)
kafka_1         |       at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.ZookeeperReadyCommand.main(ZookeeperReadyCommand.java:55)
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Zookeeper container is coming upfine. It's kafka that's causing issues. Please let me know if I am missing something somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your using bridge mode for networking, but you don't define a common network to use for zookeeper and kafka? Also, see the `examples`  directory at https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images to get started.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll I have all the containers running on bridge mode. Is it okay to run kafka and zookeeper on host or some other network? I got the current compose from these examples itself :)

Comment: Both modes (bridge + host) work.  For a host example, see https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/3.2.x/examples/kafka-single-node/docker-compose.yml (for Confluent 3.2 and Apache Kafka 0.10.2.0).